# How to put nested if conditions in single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

For a situation like this:

```
a = int(input())

if a > 6:
    right()
elif:
    left()

def right():
    print('great')

def left():
    print('less')
```

We can make the condition part a single line like this:

```
a = int(input())

left() if a > 6 else right()

def right():
    print('great')

def left():
    print('less')
```

Then what about nested if conditions like:

```
a = int(input())

if a > 0 and a < 12:
    if a > 6:
        right()
    else:
        left()
else:
    print('wrong')
```

How to put the above like code in single line (or any other simpler way)?

Comment: Why do you want to? It's more readable without that kind of mangling.

Comment: Do you have a shortage of lines or something? Making code as short as possible isn't a reasonable goal. Readability is more important overall.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be done, just that you shouldn't do it. What are you, paying for version control by the line?

Comment: Well, why *would* I give an answer that I don't think should be used? And how does whether or not I write an answer relate to whether or not I edit the question?

Comment: To improve the content on this site for others. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it as it would be less readable, and readability is important to be able to use the code.

---

As info, use parenthesis

```
(left() if a > 6 else right()) if a > 0 and a < 12 else print('wrong')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses to nest the conditional expressions.

```
(right() if a > 6 else left()) if 0 < a < 12 else print('wrong')
```